# How to implement a logical distinction in the commnad line arguments for python scripts?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to be able to pass arguments that will be passed to multiple scripts later on in an easy to read format (basically grouped for each script). I can give an example:

It is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540414/passing-parameters-into-dataproc-pyspark-job)

> use '--' to separate arguments to your job from arguments to gcloud

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster=my-dataproc \
    test-pyspark.py -- 7day 2017-11-01
```

Something exactly like this. dataproc has `--` to demarcate one set of arguments from another. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library you're using for parsing command line arguments: `argparse`, etc. It either has this feature built in (google it for the library), or you need to manually split the list of positional arguments at `.index('--')`

Answer (score 0):

It is already implemented, provided you use `argparse` to handle your command line: `--` tells argparse that everything after it should not be processed as options but as positional arguments.

If you later pass those *positional* arguments, some of them starting with a comma to a child command, it will be able to process its own options.